# In detail parsing of html files

Tags: html, parsing, webkit, gecko

I have a requirement for a project wherein I need to parse html files taking into account CSS files associated with the html page and build a detailed dom tree. I need the same detail as firebug computed/Dom tabs display. The user of my library may ask questions like:

1. The `border-left-style` for the third `div` in the `body` tag. I need to figure out what border is applied to this `div`. If the style specified by the user is `border`, then I should extract the left border style and return that value.
2. If the browser width is 1020px, then what will be the x and y coordinates of a particular node in the dom.
3. What is the width and height of the text for a particular dom element.

My application is Java based. I am wondering if I can use some parts of either Gecko or Webkit and build on top of them my library.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Andy